# Proper UV island packing/texel density workflow?

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm pretty new to Blender. I've created a scene with multiple objects, each with multiple materials (some of which are shared between objects). I've already UV unwrapped everything, but I'm wondering how to go about applying texel density (with UV Magic addon) and packing islands. My main questions are:

1. How do I choose the density to apply?
2. Should the density be applied across the entire mesh or should it be applied on a "per material" basis?
3. Same question as above, but for packing UV islands.
4. Should I apply the density and then pack islands or pack and then apply density?

I'm planning to use Quixel Mixer for texturing, if that changes anything.